# How to make on default data-filter to filter on load only .barcoffeshop not all the posts

Tags: javascript, html, css, data-filtering

*On default there are all the divs printed, I want on load to be printed only  barcoffeshop classes.
How to manipulate using js/jquery to display only barcoffeshop*

```
            <li class="filter" data-filter="all">All</li>
                <li class="filter active" data-filter=".apartment">Appartment</li>
                <li class="filter" data-filter=".barcoffeshop">Bar Coffe Shop</li>
                <li class="filter" data-filter=".hotel">Hotel</li>
                <li class="filter" data-filter=".pharmacy">Pharmacy</li>
                <li class="filter" data-filter=".vila">Vila</li>
                <li class="filter" data-filter=".office">office</li>

> class apartment below

                <div
                  class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 mix apartament"
                  style="display: inline-block"
                  data-bound=""
                >
                  <figure class="project-item imghvr-flip-vert">
                    <img
                      src="assets/img/imazhe/apartamente/apartment/BEDROOM 1 800X500.jpg"
                      alt=""
                    />
                    <figcaption>
                      <div class="overlay">
                        <a href=""><h3>Apartament</h3></a>
                        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a>
                        <a
                          href="assets/img/imazhe/apartamente/apartment/BEDROOM 1 800X500.jpg"
                          class="work-popup"
                        >
                          <i class="fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </figcaption>
                  </figure>
                </div>

   > class bacoffe shop below
                <!-- work item -->
                <div
                  class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 mix barcoffeshop"
                  style="display: inline-block"
                  data-bound=""
                >
                  <figure class="project-item imghvr-flip-vert">
                    <img
                      src="assets/img/imazhe/Bar Caffe Shop/BAR CAFE 1 800X500.jpg"
                      alt=""
                    />
                    <figcaption>
                      <div class="overlay">
                        <a href=""><h3>Bar Coffe</h3></a>
                        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a>
                        <a
                          href="assets/img/imazhe/Bar Caffe Shop/BAR CAFE 1 800X500.jpg"
                          class="work-popup"
                        >
                          <i class="fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </figcaption>
                  </figure>
                </div>
```

Is there any way to remove all the divs only on load, in order to display barcoffeshop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the list item with `data-filter` as `barcoffeeshop` and call `.focus()` on it using javaScript when the page loads.

Refer the CodePen for complete implementation: [Click here](https://codepen.io/neetigyachahar/pen/MWmGLdB)